# SpagoBI in Wordpress

Tags: spagobi

We have couple of charts on a SpagoBI server. We would like to display these charts outside of SpagoBI server, preferably we would like to display those in any java or php CMS. Take wordpress, would it be possible to display SpagoBI charts in Wordpress? Appreciate for any guidance. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [Javascript SpagoBI API](http://spagobi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/JS/README/)

also, you can get some examples from [here](https://github.com/svn2github/SpagoBI-V4x/blob/master/SpagoBISDK/WebContent/html/sdktest.html)